# How to use Freestyle with openGl render?

Tags: freestyle

Hello guys right now I want to use freestyle, but with the OpenGl render.
[image]

I'm not sure if this is possible. when I render using the openGl render image freestyle will not work, but when the Render Image (using internal or cyles it works). The reason of doing this is because the viewport could be used in order to save time, in this case I just need to render a simple logo.

Comment: Would print screen do the same trick? If you max your viewport and press print screen does it work for you? After pressing print screen ... open an image editing software like photoshop and hit paste? Or do you need it to be animated?

Comment: Maybe but what I really want is to check the result of freestyle fast. But I also need to use the power of Viewport rendering.